# Using a View as a filter criteria to another view

Tags: views

How can I a view as *is one of* filter criteria for another view, So that it provides a list of possible options?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Views filter view](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/dereine/1443726) sandbox module, which does exactly what you are asking for.

> This module will allow to filter results by another view.
>   This other view is either not active on the current site at all, then the view is executed and the result is taken.
>
> If the view on the site was runned already, the result is reused

Answer (score 0):

[Views Reference Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_filter)

> This module provides the views filter for entity ID or entity
>   reference fields:
>
> - node ID
> - user ID
> - taxonomy term ID
> - term reference field (Drupal core)
> - entity reference field ([Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Other View Filter](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/bbinkovitz/2733827), which filters a view by another view. Supports nodes, managed files, and users.